# Bidirectional RNN/LSTM/GRU using attention in PyTorch

Tags: machine-learning, pytorch, nlp, artificial-intelligence, recurrent-neural-network

I am trying to implement a bidirectional RNN using pytorch. I have short texts of variable lengths, which I tokenize and get their lengths. Each text has words inside, and I use a Word2vec model to turn each word into a vector. So a text is a list of such vectors. As I said, they differ in length, so I use `pad_sequence`, `pack_padded_sequence` and `pad_packed_sequence` to have the model read them correctly.

```
tokenized = [text_word_vectors(text, model, 100) for text in texts]
valid = [text_word_vectors(text, model, 100) for text in texts]
```

and this is a optuna case for training

```
class MultiClassDataset(Dataset):
    def __init__(self, X, y, lengths):
        self.X = X
        self.y = torch.from_numpy(y).type(torch.LongTensor)
        self.len = len(X)
        self.lengths = lengths
        
    def __getitem__(self, index):
        if self.lengths is not None:
            return self.X[index], self.y[index], self.lengths[index]
        else:
            return self.X[index], self.y[index]

    def __len__(self):
        return self.len

def objective(trial):
    lengths_train = [len(text) for text in tokenized]
    lengths_valid = [len(text) for text in valid_tokenized]

    batch_size = 240

    def collate_fn(batch):
        tweets, labels, lengths = zip(*batch)
        padded = pad_sequence([torch.FloatTensor(text) for text in texts], batch_first=True, padding_value=0.0)
        return padded, torch.LongTensor(labels), torch.LongTensor(lengths)

    transformed_dataset = MultiClassDataset(tokenized, y_train, lengths_train)
    train_loader = DataLoader(dataset=transformed_dataset, batch_size=batch_size, shuffle=True, collate_fn=collate_fn)

    transformed_valid_dataset = MultiClassDataset(valid_tokenized, y_valid, lengths_valid)
    valid_loader = DataLoader(dataset=transformed_valid_dataset, batch_size=batch_size, shuffle=False, collate_fn=collate_fn)

    trial_number = trial.number
    # Initialize lists to store losses for plotting the learning curve
    train_losses = []
    val_losses = []
    D_in = 100
    D_out = 3
    # Suggest hyperparameters to optimize
    hidden_size = trial.suggest_int('hidden_size', 64, 64)
    learning_rate = trial.suggest_float('LR', 0.0001, 0.01)
    num_layers = trial.suggest_int('num_layers', 4,4)
    dropout = trial.suggest_float('dropout', 0.4, 0.5, step=0.025)
    clip =  trial.suggest_float('clip', 0.1, 0.7, step=0.025)
    cell_type = trial.suggest_categorical('cell_type', ['GRU', 'LSTM'])
    skip =  trial.suggest_categorical('skip', [False, False])
    
    neurnet = RNN(cell_type, D_in, hidden_size, D_out, batch_size, device, num_layers, skip, dropout, True)
    
    neurnet.train()
    criterion = nn.CrossEntropyLoss()
    optimizer = optim.Adam(neurnet.parameters(), lr=learning_rate)
    scheduler = StepLR(optimizer, step_size=6, gamma=0.1)
    # Training loop
    num_epochs = 10
    for epoch in range(num_epochs):
        
        total_train_loss = 0.0
        total_train_batches = 0
        
        neurnet.train()
        # Training
        for batch_idx, (inputs, labels, lengths) in enumerate(train_loader):
            inputs, labels, lengths = inputs.to(device), labels.to(device), lengths.to(device)
            optimizer.zero_grad()
            outputs_packed = neurnet(inputs,lengths)
            loss = criterion(outputs_packed, labels)
            nn.utils.clip_grad_norm_(neurnet.parameters(), clip)
            total_train_loss += loss.item()
            loss.backward()
            optimizer.step()
            total_train_batches += 1
        # Validation
        neurnet.eval()
        total_val_loss = 0.0
        total_val_batches = 0

        with torch.no_grad():
            for batch in valid_loader:
                if len(batch) == 2:
                    val_inputs, val_labels = batch
                elif len(batch) == 3:
                    val_inputs, val_labels, lengths = batch
                else:
                    raise ValueError("Unexpected number of elements in the batch")
                val_inputs = val_inputs.to(device)
                lengths = lengths.to(device)
                val_outputs = neurnet(val_inputs,lengths)
                val_loss = criterion(val_outputs, val_labels.to(device))  # Compute loss
                total_val_loss += val_loss.item()  # Accumulate total_val_loss
                # Convert logits to predictions
                preds = torch.argmax(val_outputs, dim=1).cpu().numpy()
                # Collect predictions and labels for precision, recall, and F1 score calculation
                total_val_batches += 1  # Increment total_val_batches

        average_val_loss = total_val_loss / total_val_batches
        average_train_loss = total_train_loss / total_train_batches
        
        train_losses.append(average_train_loss)
        val_losses.append(average_val_loss)
        
        # Update the learning rate based on validation loss
#         lr_scheduler.step(average_val_loss)
        scheduler.step()
        print(f"Epoch {epoch}, Loss: {average_train_loss}, Valuation Loss: {average_val_loss}, Learning Rate: {optimizer.param_groups[0]['lr']}")
        # Report intermediate results to Optuna
        trial.report(average_val_loss, epoch)

        # Handle pruning based on the intermediate value
        if trial.should_prune():
            raise optuna.TrialPruned()
```

**My problem is at how to define the model!**

```
class RNN(nn.Module):
    """
      Wrapper module for RNN, LSTM, GRU cells using pytorch api. The output is fed to a FFN for classification.
    """
    def __init__(self, cell_type, input_size, hidden_size, output_size, batch_size,device,num_layers=2, skip_connections=False, dropout=0.0,attention=False, num_heads=1):
        super(RNN, self).__init__()
        cells = {
          "RNN" : nn.RNN,
          "LSTM"    : nn.LSTM,
          "GRU"     : nn.GRU
        }
        
        self.hidden_size = hidden_size
        self.num_layers = num_layers
        self.input_size = input_size
        self.cell_type = cell_type
        self.batch_size = batch_size
        self.dropout = nn.Dropout(dropout)
        self.skip_connections = skip_connections
        self.attention = attention
        
        if not skip_connections:
            self.rnn = cells[cell_type](         # Pick the specific model
                bidirectional=True,
                input_size=input_size,           # Number of features for each time step
                hidden_size=hidden_size,         # rnn hidden units
                batch_first=True,       # input & output will has batch size as 1s dimension. e.g. (batch, time_step, input_size)
                num_layers=num_layers,
                dropout=dropout,
                device=device
            )
        else:
            self.rnn = nn.ModuleList()
            for i in range(num_layers):
                if i != 0:
                    self.rnn.append(cells[cell_type](
                        bidirectional=True,
                        input_size=hidden_size*2,           # Number of features for each time step
                        hidden_size=hidden_size,         # rnn hidden units
                        batch_first=True,       # input & output will has batch size as 1s dimension. e.g. (batch, time_step, input_size)
                        num_layers=1,
                        device=device
                    ))
                else:
                    self.rnn.append(cells[cell_type](
                        bidirectional=True,
                        input_size=input_size,           # Number of features for each time step
                        hidden_size=hidden_size,         # rnn hidden units
                        batch_first=True,       # input & output will has batch size as 1s dimension. e.g. (batch, time_step, input_size)
                        num_layers=1,
                        device=device
                    ))
        self.out = nn.Linear(hidden_size*2, output_size,device=device) # Feed forward network
        
        if self.attention:
            self.Q = nn.Linear(hidden_size*2,hidden_size*2, bias=False, device=device)
            self.K = nn.Linear(hidden_size*2,hidden_size*2, bias=False, device=device)
            self.V = nn.Linear(hidden_size*2,hidden_size*2, bias=False, device=device)
            self.att = nn.MultiheadAttention(self.hidden_size*2, num_heads=num_heads ,batch_first=True, device=device)

    def forward(self, x,lengths):
        # x shape (batch, time_step, input_size)
        # r_out shape (batch, time_step, output_size)
        # h_n shape (n_layers, batch, hidden_size)
        # h_c shape (n_layers, batch, hidden_size)
        inputs_packed = pack_padded_sequence(x, lengths.cpu(), batch_first=True, enforce_sorted=False)
        if not self.skip_connections:
            if self.cell_type == 'LSTM':
                r_out, (h_n, h_c) = self.rnn(inputs_packed)
            else:
                r_out, h_n = self.rnn(inputs_packed)
            
            r_in, _ = pad_packed_sequence(r_out, batch_first=True)
            print(r_in.shape)
            # Bidirectional
#             out = torch.cat((h_n[-2, :, :], h_n[-1, :, :]), dim=1)
            # Now, proceed with the linear layer
#             print("Before linear: out", out.shape)
#             out = self.out(out)
    
            if self.attention:
                Q = self.Q(r_in)
                K = self.K(r_in)
                V = self.V(r_in)
                att, _ = self.att(Q, K, V)
                att = att.squeeze(dim=1)
                out = att + r_in
                print(out.shape)
                t = torch.cat((out[-2, :, :], out[-1, :, :]), dim=1)
                print(t.shape)
                out = t
            else:
                out = torch.cat((h_n[-2, :, :], h_n[-1, :, :]), dim=1)
                print(out.shape)
            return self.out(out)
#             print("Out", out.shape)
        else:
```

The problem I have is regarding the different dimensions. My process of though is that, the input (x) and its lengths get inside the model. My first job is to remove the padding, for which i use `pack_padded_sequence`. Since its already padded, this will remove the padding. Now I can feed that into the RNN. After that, I have to feed the output of the model, into the different heads for attention. However, in order to do that, I have to repack the output of the model, from a PackedSequence object, in order to get a tensor. this works fine thus far. From `print(r_in.shape)` after the pad_packed_sequence I get [240,50,128] which is the [batch_size,length,hidden_size*2] as I understand it. The `print(out.shape)` also yields [240,50,128] which is correct so far well. I then want to use that to concatenate the last two layers as discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63121983/bidirectional-rnn-implementation-pytorch) but the tensor I get then is torch.Size([50, 256]) (`print(t.shape)`). This yields a  `mat1 and mat2 shapes cannot be multiplied (50x256 and 128x3)` error, from the self.out(out). What am I doing wrong? Why doesnt the concatenation work?